# How to keep the ANSI code when I write it in a file

Tags: r, slurm

I want to write in a file a word with a code ANSI but slurm remove it leash only the word

**job.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH --job-name=test
    #SBATCH --nodes=1               # number of nodes
    #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1     # number of cores
    #SBATCH --time=24:00:00          # walltime
    #SBATCH --output=out.txt
    #SBATCH --error=err.txt

module load R
Rscript test.R
```

**test.R**

```
library(crayon)
fileConn<-file("output.txt")
x <- as.character(yellow("hello world"))
writeLines(x, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

**output.txt**

```
hello world
# i want this \033[33mhello wrold\033[39m
```

---

When I use the Rscript command only, it works as I wish (it writes the ANSI code in the output.txt file), but if I go through slurm with the sbatch job.sh command, it does not write the code ANSI.